# How to use render partial with webgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I understand how to execute the render partial but how to refresh a webgrid with the new data
Razor syntax please.

```
$.get( '@Url.Action("details","user", new { id = Model.ID } )',
   function(data) {     $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data); });
```

where the user controller has an action named details that does:

```
public ActionResult Details( int id ) {    
 var model = ...get user from db using id...     
 return Partial( "UserDetails", model ); }
```

#### End result should be something like this

Like   var grid = new WebGrid(source:Model.UserDetails,....

Comment: where you able to resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your partialView Change your grid declaration to something like :

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
//defaultSort: "DataId",
ajaxUpdateCallback: "GridUpdate",
ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid"
rowsPerPage: 50);
```

ensure that your .GetHtml method has :

```
@grid.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
```

//.. rest of the options here
)
and add the below to your Index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GridUpdate(data) {
    $('#gridview').html(data);
}
</script>
```

remember to put

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

in your parial to get only the webgrid (without the whole template)